# Why was my question closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Can anyone chime in on why [my question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33286/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-slow-down-an-airliner-on-a-long-runway) is closed as a duplicate?

Fortunately I got the answer I wanted before it was closed, but I truly can't see why any answers in the linked question applies. However if enough people here are saying they're duplicate, there must be a gap between what I intend to express, and how others perceived it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this—

> Another way to phrase the question is, in an ideal situation with perfect environment factors, what is the best way to slow down an airliner after landing?

—was the culprit. I didn't VTC, but small editing and I would agree with you.

Because mainly there's the aspect of what if something went wrong on said long-runway-far-exit. Right? At least that's what I think you meant. Which would not make it a dupe, i.e., best (per SOP's) lazy way to brake + potential downsides.

Comment: Thanks, I've rephrased that part. Hope others will agree.